# Node.js receiving external static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Say I currently have two servers at `www.random1.com` and `www.random2.com`. If my current node.js server runs through `www.random1.com` and requires to get static files (html,js,css) from `www.random2.com` (ex.www.random2.com/static/javascript/script.js), what methods are there to go about doing this?

My main aims in achieving this are the following:

1. reuse static files from different servers
2. slightly modify static files received from another server before rendering them
   in the current server (ex. remove/add a bit of html, replace .css in html file, etc)

Example:

- Request to `www.random1.com/index.html`
- Server at `www.random1.com` gets `www.random2.com/index.html` (along with .js, .css files referred)
- Server at `www.random1.com` makes slight modifications to received file
- Server renders to `www.random.com/index.html` (with required javascript, css files in original html file also loaded, hence I'd have to get those as well)

I'm currently trying to get this done through Express, but general Node.js implementations are also very much welcome.

Note:

This is a question I'm asking for future reference in case there arises some situation that I have limited access to the static file server (ex.only being allowed access to the server when at work, etc.). I understand that it would realistically be easier to implement an approach where I would either just keep two copies of the same resources, or a source management system that I could branch out from and merge.

All answers are welcome.

Please show me the breadths of your intellectual powers and experience.

Comment: If I may ask 1.) why are you doing this? 2.) What modifications are you doing exactly at random1?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Sorry if I've made it unclear. 1) I'm trying to reuse resources that I've already put up on another server. I'm only making tiny changes so I'd rather not put up 2 copies of practically the same thing and have to maintain them both. Plus, the sites I'm working on have different purposes; hence I'd rather separate resources than keep them all on the same server (or use templates). 2) What I'm trying to do at the moment is take the original html file and just make slight adjustments to the body. I'd prefer a general solution though for future reference for any related work

Comment: Without knowing much about your project I think what you are trying to do sounds overly complicated and not a good idea. Before embarking in a rather unorthodox approach like you are trying to do I would start rather keep two copies of the files and get the sites fully functional first.

Comment: @HectorCorrea I already have. I'm now just looking for a different approach wondering if I can achieve the aim in the question so that I can better maintain files.

Comment: It sounds like a good solution would be for you to use some type of version control, and then to create a branch for each server that has a slightly different set of files. Then when you make changes, you can merge them with all branches. But I'm not sure if you're after source control or just a way to "share" files between two servers?

Comment: @therin Thanks for the reply. I'm looking more along the lines of "sharing" files across servers than source control in case there arises any situation that I'm restricted for whatever reason access to servers. I'm really starting to realise that I've been bad at relaying what I'm wanting to ask. Is there anything else that I've been unclear about?

Comment: Are you trying to use random2.com as a backup server for random1.com?

Comment: @therin No, I'm just trying to reuse random2.com's resources. random1.com's a completely different site from random2.com with a different purpose.